# Proving the combinatorial expression

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Ok I've been reading in my probability book about the different methods on how to count and I'm just trying to dissect the usual combinatorial formula: $$\binom {a} {b} = \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

Everything makes sense excpet I can't figure out how the $(a-b)!$ term arises. The other two terms are fine with $a!$ being the number of ordered samples  while $b!$ is the number of permutations for each sample, but that difference is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order your $a$ items, there will be $a!$ ways. However for choosing a subset of size $b$ (which is the first $b$ items in your ordering), not only does the ordering of the first $b$ items not matter, but also the ordering of the remaining $a-b$ items outside the chosen subset does not matter. This is why you divide by both factorials.

Comment: yes i see.  $(a-b)!b!$ is the number of ways to order each sample. I was thinking only $b!$ was the number of ways to order each sample. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a-b is the number of samples left. Think about it.

Selecting 5 red balls from an urn with 5 red balls and 9 blue balls is 
equivalent to selecting 9 blue balls from an urn with 5 red balls and 9 blue balls.

Answer (score 0):

**sampling** $b$ from $a$:

$1^\text{st}$.may be chosen in $a$ ways 
$2^\text{nd}$.may be chosen in $a-1$ ways 
${}\,\vdots$
$b^\text{th}$. may be chosen in $a-b+1$ ways

total possible samples $a(a-1)\cdots(a-b+1)$

**equivalence**

the $b$ sampled items give the same sample when chosen in any of the $b!$ different possible orders.

hence number of samples of $b$ things from $a$ is 
$$
\frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-b+1)}{b!} = \frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-b+1)(a-b)!}{b!(a-b)!}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}
$$